# asp.net VB How to select all matching values on one listbox to another?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

I have two listboxes a DivisionListBox and a SitesListbox. In the division listbox i have Store Group ID value and in the sites listbox i have multiple values that share the Store Group ID with the division listbox.

What i'm trying to do is when i select a Store Group ID value in the DivisionListbox it selects all the items in the SitesListbox that match the selected Store Group ID value.

What would be the correct way to implement this ?

**How i populate the listboxes**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    FillDivisionListbox()
    FillSitesListbox()
End Sub

Private Sub FillDivisionListbox()

    Try
        divList = SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT STR_GRP_ID, CAST(STR_GRP_ID AS varchar) + ' - ' + GROUP_DESC AS IDDesc 
                                    FROM Store_Group_Desc")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    DivisionListBox.DataSource = divList
    DivisionListBox.DataTextField = "IDDesc"
    DivisionListBox.DataValueField = "str_grp_id"
    DivisionListBox.DataBind()


End Sub

Private Sub FillSitesListbox()

    Try
        siteList = SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT d.str_grp_id, (Cast(s.Str_ID As varchar) + ' - ' + s.Nm + ' [ ' + Cast(d.str_grp_id As varchar) + ' ]' ) as IDDesc
                            FROM Retail_Stores left outer join store_group d on ( s.str_id = d.str_id ) 
                                ORDER BY s.Str_ID")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    SitesListBox.DataSource = siteList
    SitesListBox.DataTextField = "IDDesc"
    SitesListBox.DataValueField = "str_grp_id"
    SitesListBox.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the DivisionListBox onselected method loop thru the items in the sitelistbox and mark selected if the GroupID Matched the GroupID of the item in the DivisionListBox.
e.g.

```
 foreach(ListItem item in SiteListBox.Items)
 {
      if(item.Value == DivisionListBox.SelectedValue)
       {
          item.selected = true;
       }
 }
```